# Extract substring within a given string

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've read and attempted to extract a substring from a given string with awk, sed or grep but I am unable to get it working or think how to accomplish this.

I have the string below which describes configurations of my VMs:

```
config: diskSizeGb: 100 diskType: pd-standard imageType: COS_CONTAINERD machineType: e2-micro metadata: disable-legacy-endpoints: 'true' preemptible: true status: RUNNING version: 1.19.9
```

How can I extract a substring for example, "preemptible: true" or "status: RUNNING" knowing that the values can be different for each VM?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- the VM config name/value pairs may not be in the same order
- config names and values are single strings with no embedded white space
- each config name is preceded by (at least) one space, and followed immediately by a colon (`:`)
- there may be multiple spaces between the colon (`:`) and the config value; we want to maintain these spaces in the output

One idea using `sed` and a capture groups:

```
# note: extra spaces placed between 'version:' and '1.19.9'

cfg_string="config: diskSizeGb: 100 diskType: pd-standard imageType: COS_CONTAINERD machineType: e2-micro metadata: disable-legacy-endpoints: 'true' preemptible: true status: RUNNING version:   1.19.9"

for config in preemptible status version
do
        echo "++++++++++++++ ${config}"
        sed -nE "s/.* (${config}:[ ]*[^ ]*).*/\1/p" <<< "${cfg_string}"
done
```

`sed` details:

- `-nE` - disable default printing of the input (we'll use `/p` to explicitly print our capture group; enable `E`xtended regex support
- `.* (${config}:[ ]*[^ ]*).*` - match variable number of characters (`.*`) + a space ( ) + `${config}` + a colon (`:`) + one or more spaces (`[ ]*`) + everything that follows that is not a space (`[^ ]*`) + the rest of the input (`.*`); the parens mark the start/end of the capture group (only one capture group in this case)
- `\1` - reference capture group #1 (ie, everything inside of the parens)
- `/p` - print (the capture group)

This generates:

```
++++++++++++++ preemptible
preemptible: true
++++++++++++++ status
status: RUNNING
++++++++++++++ version
version:   1.19.9                # extra spaces maintained
```

**NOTES:**

- obviously an invalid config name (eg, `stat`, `versions`) is going to produce no output
- the `sed` results could be captured in a variable for further testing/processing (would address issue of an invalid config name)

Comment: wow @markp-fuso, that was exactly what I was looking for and you are right with your assumptions. It can change orders based on each VM. Is there any chance you can break down the sed command so I can understand what each piece does?

Comment: @CaioT added some notes about `sed`

Comment: Much appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here a possibile solution:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

data="config: diskSizeGb: 100 diskType: pd-standard imageType: COS_CONTAINERD machineType: e2-micro metadata: disable-legacy-endpoints: 'true' preemptible: true status: RUNNING version: 1.19.9"

preemptible=$(echo ${data} | cut -d ' ' -f 14)
echo "preemptible = ${preemptible}"

status=$(echo ${data} | cut -d ' ' -f 16)
echo "status = ${status}"
```

Comment: Hi Antonio, thank you for the input. The 14 and 16 values are the white spaces count right? Is there any more reliable way to extract these strings? The reason I ask is because the config of VMs can vary and one can have more spaces than other configs within the data variable.

Comment: Tte `cut` command splits the string by spaces, so the value 14 represents the 14th field, thus **preemptible**.

Comment: Note that `echo ${data}` is itself buggy. If you have `value: *`, you're going to get that `*` replaced with a list of filenames in your current directory. **Always** quote your expansions: `echo "$data"` -- curly braces are entirely optional, quotes are not.